# How to make this java script show the ads at the end of the video

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a plugin called beTube Ads that works with the betheme wordpress theme. This plugins can show some ads at the start of the video, when the video loads. How to make it show the ads ad the end of the video ????

This is the java script :

```
    (function(jQuery) {
    jQuery.fn.advCounter = function(){
        var src = this.find('.video-plugin-div').children('iframe').attr('src');
        this.find('.video-plugin-div').children('iframe').attr('src' , src + '?autoplay=1&controls=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&widgetid=1');
        var counter = 6;
        this.addClass('added');
        var tBtn = jQuery(this);
        setInterval(function(){
            counter--;
            if(counter >= 0){
                var button = tBtn.find('#count');
                button.html(counter);
                jQuery(button).show();
            }
            if (counter === 0) {
                jQuery(button).hide();
                tBtn.find('.skip-video').show();
                clearInterval(counter);
            }

        }, 1000);
        //hide betube ad div
        jQuery('.skip-video').on('click', function(){
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('.tabs-title').on('click', function(){
        var img = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');
        if(jQuery(img).hasClass('added')){        
        }else{
            jQuery(img).advCounter();
        }
    });    

});
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {      
    jQuery('#player1').advCounter();
});
```

Anyone can please help me ??? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have reference to the  element, then

```
var video = $('selector for video element')
video.on('ended', function() {
 // Your code to run the advertisement
})
```

Comment: I am new with java, if you can help me a little more please? where i should add this and can you help me with the selector? should i post a link to a demo page here ?

Comment: Hey. Sorry I didn't check back this post. If this answer, please accept the answer or if you need any more explanation regarding this question, let me know.